# 2 fields the same in XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I have 3 tags called 'Url' in my XML feed that I am trying to extract data from using jQuery. The first 2 are image files, the other is a web link.

One is nested at this level

```
Offer > Images > Image > Url
```

Another is at this level:

```
Offer > Images > ZoomImage > Url
```

The last is at this level:

```
Offer > Url
```

If I use the following code, I only get the first URL

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "datafile.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Offer').each(function(){
                        var title = $(this).find('Title').text();
                        var url = $(this).find('Url').text();
                        var description =  $(this).find('Description').text();  
$('<div class="title"</div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                    });
```

I actually want all 3 URLs returned separately to use in my code. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = $(this).children('Url').text();
var urlImage = $(this).find('Images ZoomImage Url').text();
var urlZoomImage = $(this).find('Images Image Url').text();
```

Just be more specific in your targeting using `.find()` and `.children()`